# What is this notation?

Tags: notation, tensors

I don't recognize the notation used for the $x_i$ *directions* below (passage from textbook).

> The components of a vector depend on the base vectors used to describe the components. This will also be true for tensors.
>
> Let $\hat{e_1}, \hat{e_2}, \hat{e_3}$ be unit vectors in the direction of $x_{1^-}, x_{2^-}, x_{3^-}$, respectively, of a rectangular Cartesian coordinate system. Under the transformation $\boldsymbol{T}$, these vectors $\hat{e_1}, \hat{e_2}, \hat{e_3}$ become $\boldsymbol{T}\hat{e_1}, \boldsymbol{T}\hat{e_2}, \boldsymbol{T}\hat{e_3}$. Each of these can be written...

The book goes on without mentioning the notation anywhere nearby. And this is the first mention in the book.

Comment: I would interpret it as $(-1,0,0),(0,-1,0)$ and $(0,0,-1)$, ie. unit negative coordinate in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

He writes phrases like, "... about the $x_3$-axis... " quite a bit I'm seeing. So, in context, I'm gathering he mean *axis* by the dash symbol. That is, it's not a minus sign.

Comment: In that case it would be $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ the "standard" unit vectors. But then I don't see the need to put a hat on them, since ,$e_1,e_2,e_3$ would fit well. Somehow, these $\hat{e_1},\hat{e_2},\hat{e_3}$ should differ from the standard ones. Can you give us a reference for that book ?

Comment: Intro to Continua Mechanics by Lai, etc. 4th edition. Chapter 2 material.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Ok, from the reference you gave me, I found an excerpt on google books.

In this version of the book, the author says $x_1$-,$x_2$-,$x_3$-axes so it is effectively the standard vectors $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

Although there are not hats on the $e_i$ in this third edition. It seems this part has been changed in fourth edition and they omit the word **axes**, probably an impression mistake.

Comment: Well based on the context of the book (so far that I've read) it seems like he's not referring to any spcific axes at all. Rather, just some arbitrary axes where the bold e's represent unit vectors with respect to that cartesian coordinate system.